# Twitter API returns NULL on XAMPP

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm trying to make a call to the Twitter API.

In short my problem is the same one as described [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/21). Making my call I get `NULL` on a `var_dump()` of the result.

**However**

cURL works fine, I have included the newest version of the *twitter-api-php* script and all the tokens, keys and secrets are correct.

I'm working on a local XAMPP installation. Does this cause the problem? But it seems to work for other people. Is php configured wrong in my case? Or did I simply miss a semicolon (which I doubt because I don't get any errors)?

**Here is my code:**

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once('.\libs\TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => '############',
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => '############',
    'consumer_key' => '########',
    'consumer_secret' => '###########'
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?screen_name=J7mbo';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->performRequest();

var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Comment: **Do you have cURL enabled properly in XAMPP?** - Does your `phpinfo()` show this to be the case?

Comment: As far as I can see it says:`cURL support  enabled` in `phpinfo()`

Comment: Could you write a simple cURL test script to make sure it's working as expected? People who have had issues with this before seemed to have cURL set up incorrectly - so let's 100% rule this out before continuing.

Comment: I ran some test scripts and they all said, the module was loaded, the only script I coul not get to run was the one at the end of the [page](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/What-is-cURL-And-How-To-Enable-It-For-XAMPP-183.php). Does that give you a hint?

Comment: [http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm) this example worked perfectly btw.

Comment: Andre, check out the github issue you posted. Someone added some info there and also check out [this link](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/). Something to do with certs with your local build. Might be helpful?

Comment: It works now, thanks! Posted it as an answer, so people might find it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like Jimbo pointed out in the comments above, the solution can be found [here](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/)

According to the article, the Windows PHP distribution doesn't come with an up-to-date bundle of the CA root certificates.
However, the bundle can be downloaded [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). I put it under `C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem`.

The second step is to add `curl.cainfo=c:\xampp\php\cacert.pem` at the end of your php.ini file.
Change the path to your folder where you saved the .pem-file.

Restart Apache and now the problem should be solved!

Thanks!

Comment: That is what makes StackOverflow better than any message board, hope my new answer is okay!
Thank you

Comment: Andre - you should mark this as a 'correct answer' by ticking it on the left!