# Trying to fix property of non-object error PHP twitter Xampp

Tags: php, netbeans, twitter, xampp

I have used the following code on c9.io to query and display tweets using Twitter Api which displayed tweets perfectly on c9. However, when running the same code using netbeans and Xampp on my computer, I get the following error

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 44`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 44"`

Here is my code for twittersearch.php. Is their a setting with xampp that needs to be edited?

```
<html>
<h1>Welcome to Twitter API Search</h1>
<head></head>
<h2>Search tweets containing keywords:</h2>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="q" size="35" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
#### Include the class file ####
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
if(!empty($_POST['q'])) {

    #### Set access tokens ####

        $settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => "83483102-js8XSKtqa8WfQgzuscXzJTZhxWpWXKvYe7XDdrOir",
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => "Vz5grexMBCQwcWj8imZSkwFmpWuKfuIEv3cFzdzQDNPf3",
            'consumer_key' => "zbFgHw7Ne8iRWv9L2UDODw",
            'consumer_secret' => "r6s6lapJvypNT5dHmdJNsCDHriPezWlPWgKz5TauBo"
        );

    #### Choose URL and Request Method ####

        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
        $requestMethod = 'GET';
        //$getfield = '?q='.urlencode($_POST['q']);
        $getfield = '?q='.urlencode($_POST['q']);


    #### Perform the request! ####
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $ret = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                     ->performRequest();

    $json = json_decode($ret);
    //var_dump($twitter);
    foreach($json->statuses as $tweet) {
        echo '<b><h2>Tweet: </h2></b>'.$tweet->text.'<br />';
        echo '<b>By: </b>'.$tweet->user->name.'<br /><br />';
    }
}
```

If more information is required regarding my question, please let me know.

Comment: `$json->statuses` is not of a type that PHP can iterate over. What's the output of `var_dump($json);` just before that `foreach` loop?

Comment: Var_dump($json) returns null which doesnt make sense which points to authorization. But, when I ran the same code on c9.io , it does not display any error and displays all tweets correctly

Comment: Do you have any idea why the $json object is returning null?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace:

```
foreach($json->statuses as $tweet) {
    echo '<b><h2>Tweet: </h2></b>'.$tweet->text.'<br />';
    echo '<b>By: </b>'.$tweet->user->name.'<br /><br />';
}
```

by:

```
if($json->errors) {
    foreach($json->errors as $error) {
        echo $error->message . '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    foreach($json->statuses as $tweet) {
        echo '<b><h2>Tweet: </h2></b>'.$tweet->text.'<br />';
        echo '<b>By: </b>'.$tweet->user->name.'<br /><br />';
    }        
}
```

Comment: I still get the same errors  after replacing my foreach look with the if else statement you gave me"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 50

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 55

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 55"

Comment: Please paste here output of the `var_dump($json);` before `if($json->errors) {`

Comment: output:NULL 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 51

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 56

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-api-php\twittersearch.php on line 56

Comment: Looks like problem with curl or json. What do you have on `var_dump($ret)`?

Comment: var_dump($ret) returns bool(false)

Comment: I checked and Curl is enabled in my php.ini file   extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: Your code works fine for me. There are no bugs. Please check your environment configuration and web server logs.

Comment: If you want to print your php configuration, use `phpinfo();` in your code.

Comment: maybe this could help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574055/twitter-api-returns-null-on-xampp?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your help. The main issue was that I needed a Curl ssl certificate which I downloaded and enabled in php.ini. My code is working fine now